# Building a website with Backendless

Tags: wordpress, web, backendless

I want to build a website with backendless so when it's time to go mobile all the data can remain on the same server and will be easily accessible. I know CSS and HTML but I don't want to design the website. Which website builder should I use so that it can easily be integrated with backendless?

Comment: Check out Squarespace, you can add custom code there. If nothing, why not purchase a bootstrap template ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is go to any website you like, go to File and select "Save Page As..." and download the website.

Next, open up the *.html and tinker around with it to your liking. Once you finish, just upload those files to your web host and hence no backend!

I do this to take components I like or see how something is built.